# XCode: Function argument indentation

Tags: xcode, indentation, xcode3.2

I was unable to find any solution of my specific issue. I'm using Xcode 3.2. I'd like to indent the next line of function argument just one step in from the previous line:

```
somevariable = pow(
    a,
    b);
```

However, Xcode's syntax-aware indenting insists on converting the above into:

```
somevariable = pow(
                   a,
                   b);
```

Where the arguments are aligned with opening parenthesis of the function.

How can I make indenting be configured to match my preference?

Comment: +1 good question. This is one of the more annoying things about XCode.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this. And I am using Xcode 8.3. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, this is a 10 year old issue, has anyone found any solutions to this?

Comment: Still no apparent solution in 2022...

Comment: And now in 2023...

Answer (score 2):

XCode (at least the version I have, 3.1.3) has a preferences pane called "indentation" that lets you click on/off a checkmark next to several characters such as semicolon, return,etc.

If you turn **OFF** the checkmark for return and semicolon, you can control the most important parts of your own indenting.

For instance, I declare my variables at the head of the function, and I like them flush; whereas XCode as first installed insisted on bringing them to the same level as the code.

I turned off the semicolon, and presto, it'll leave them there. Most of the time. It still screws them up during copy/pasta actions, but mostly it behaves. :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to put the parentheses on the new line too. You will have something like this:

```
auto somevariable = pow
  (a,
   b);
```

Not the most elegant solution but the most effective if you want an automatically indentation from Xcode and if you are under a number of line constraint.